# Negative Jira filter which negates other filters

Tags: filter, jira, jql

I have several filters in Jira like "Not a Story" or "Not a Bug".
However, sometimes I would like to filter only this issue and
I would like not to create additional filters like "Stories" or "Bugs".

Is there a possibility to create a general "Not" filter that will negate other filters?
I cannot find this possibility in Jira...

I tried to make something like `NOT in filter in ("Filter for BRD board")` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using filter id instead of filter name.

```
NOT in filter in ("10302")
```

Comment: I tried to made it but it doesn't filter by id :<